# I am happier now

Tags: knowledge, story

Narrator:

I am one of your typical first world citizens. I got my hobbies, but nothing too special.

I hate cleaning. I find it boring, and a chore. And I hate it even more, when I *have* to do *any amount* of cleaning right in the middle of my hobby!

It was a long time ago, and I was in a bar with friends. I got drunk rather quickly. I remember one of my friends saying a bizarre story about people jumping from their balconies. But when someone that was already falling grabbed another that was ready to jump, then they became another copy of the same person.

....Anyway. The good part is, that due to this thing, which I remember rather unclearly, I am now able to do my hobby without interruptions for cleaning!

**What is the true story behind the narrators' fuzzy thoughts?**

Edit: same person -> another copy of

Edit2: There are two main points. The balcony fall stuff, and the cleaning stuff. I remember the first, but have forgotten the second.

Tip:

> Science

Answer (score 10, accepted):

The narrator kept having to clean

> His or her glasses

The friend in the bar was explaining

> the process of [stimulated emission](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Stimulated_emission). A person (electron) on a balcony (higher energy level) is grabbed by another person (incident photon) and [the released energy] becomes a copy of that person (second photon, identical to the first).

This is the principle behind

> Lasers, and corrective eye surgery

Afterwards, the narrator

> No longer needs his/her glasses, and can carry out the hobby uninterupted.

But what was the hobby? It must obviously involve

> Wearing glasses, so maybe something requiring good eyesight?

and could possibly involve

> Glasses steaming up?

So I'm going to guess at

> Stamp collecting, [using hot water](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=uaYKdK7A2OY) / steam to help remove the stamps from the paper envelope

Comment: You are correct! As stated, I don't remember the hobby exactly - but your 4 points totally cover the answer.

Comment: Thanks for the tick mark! I was hoping the hobby part would ring a bell with you, maybe someone else with personal experience of the problem can come up with an alternative to that part of the puzzle. The only other thing I can think of is (rot13) oveq jngpuvat (ovabphynef znex tynffrf)

Answer (score 7):

My guess is...

> The narrator is speaking about the "True Story", The matrix.

So, the citizens hobby..

> Hacking (as Neo)

In reference to the cleaning..

> Working as a "clean" programmer, data cleansing etc

People jumping from their balconies..

> The "agents" as they become someone else, taking over the body code.

The citizen then...

> Departs the matrix, allowing him to join anytime he wants and be in control, effectively hacking all the time.

Comment: Welcome to Puzzling.SE! Can you explain why you believe this is the correct answer? How does it match the riddle?

Comment: Nice guess, I think the "People jumping from their balconies.." part might fit into  when Neo wakes from the Matrix and looks around viewing the pods humans are kept in, before being flushed down a tube, and collected by the Nebuchadnezzar

Comment: Welcome to puzzling! Good try....not the correct answer though. You started on a tough one...

Answer (score 6):

This is a stretch, but are you talking about

> Memory management in computer programming?

I hate cleaning.

> This is a common sentiment among developers who have had to do manual memory management.  A necessary activity when doing the "fun" hobby of developing.  And if you don't do it, you have problems

I remember one of my friends saying a bizarre story about people jumping from their balconies.

> "People" could be unused resources in program that are dumped by some other application (a "garbage collector")

But when someone that was already falling grabbed another that was ready to jump, then they became the same person.

> The free'd resources become re-usable and can be re-purposed, "becoming" a new resource

The good part is, that due to this thing, which I remember rather unclearly, I am now able to do my hobby without interruptions for cleaning!

> With "garbage collection", the developer is free to develop without having to worry about cleaning up unused resources.

Comment: Not the intended answer, but very creative!

Answer (score 3):

Could the friends have been

> using a metaphor for marriage?

And the narrator

> ignored the implications of the 'jumping off a balcony' part and got married anyway, and his spouse handles cleaning during his hobby?

Comment: Nope, it's not that.

Answer (score 1):

Your hobby might be

> Dancing

And your solution is

> To attach mops and dusters to your limbs so that you clean while you do your hobby.

Comment: What about the story?

Comment: Thought it was just a metaphor for having two things going at once

Comment: Ohh. I see. Still, not the answer.

Answer (score -11):

Could the hobby be

> masturbation

When he fell off the balcony,

> he fell with another woman and became a woman

Therefore, he doesn't need to clean up in the middle of his hobby because

> women don't ejaculate after orgasm

A stretch, but maybe?

Comment: This.. is.. kinda..

Comment: kinda...not the answer